# How to do that pattern for input html5?

Tags: html, input

I need to generate such pattern for my input, for example:

```
+375 29 911-91-91
```

in general, it looks like this:

```
+375 XX XXX-XX-XX
```

Note the spaces!

I tried this:

```
[\+][\ ]\d{3}[\ ]\d{2}\d{3}[\-]\d{2}[\-]\d{2}
```

Will this work in IE?

Comment: Did what you had tried work or not, and why didn't you try it on IE yourself?

Comment: @EitanT if i write that i try didn't you think what it mean? it works not as i need!

Comment: you didn't specify what was the problem with what you wrote, that's why I asked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\+\d{3}\s\d{2}\s\d{3}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}
```

Should work. You also don't need to put the square brackets [ and ] around every character unless you want to do an or [a|b] test or you need to do a range of characters [a-z].

Comment: Works in javascript when I tested it: /\+\d{3}\s\d{2}\s\d{3}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}/.test("+375 29 911-91-91"). What browser are you using? The pattern attribute works in all major browsers, except Internet Explorer and Safari.

Comment: all ok, trouble was in " but i need ' in rails. Also how to do for another input only letters? Like this? [A-z] and for russian would be [А-я] wright?

Comment: \w Would be a better fit. It matches all "word characters" whereas that [А-я] might not work, browsers and non-ascii characters mixing is a bad idea.

Comment: А is russian first symbol too)

Answer (score 0):

+\s*\d{3}\s+\d{2}\s+\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}